# Modify JSON File and Use It in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to call my JSON file and use it in the AngularJS.

So I wrote a code like below. It however seems like this method does not work. In my opinion, this does not work because my JSON file has some what weird format.

```
 $http.get('data_type_1.json').success(function(response){
  $scope.questions = response;
})
```

My JSON file has format like this.

```
{
"0":{ "category1": "----", 
      "category2": "----"},
"1":{ "category1": "----", 
      "category2": "----"},
"2":{"category1": "----", 
      "category2": "----"},
...
...
..

}
```

So all I want to do is call "category 1,2" and do ng-repeat.

anyone can help me?

Comment: Is your $http request actually working? Does it appear in your debugging tools network panel? Are you getting error messages? How does this "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

You have an object so use object syntax

```
<div ng-repeat="(num, obj) in questions">
   Number: {{num}} 
   Category 1: {{obj.category1}}
</div>
```

Comment: repeat part, I can do it. Can you help me with calling JSON part

Comment: request should work as shown if path is right and json is valid. Add error handling to request. Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Nothing appears when I use code. 
So I am now copy pasted DATA in JSON file. in my script